# Is a torus locally isometric to the real plane?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Please correct me if I am wrong:

A torus **is not** locally isometric to $\mathbb{R}^2$ because two points that are "local to" each other on the torus *are not necessarrily* "local to" each other in the real plane.

Or how would you put local isometry in simple terms?

Thank you :)

Comment: Depends on which metric you have on the torus.

Comment: In the question I am considering, the metric is not specified. Maybe it is implied that the metric is an extension of the metric on the real plane? But, it does not specify a metric.

Comment: (1) Look up the definition of "locally isometric"; the meaning you apparently have in mind is not the meaning that I'm accustomed to. (2) I don't think it makes much sense to ask about local isometry when no metric is given.

Comment: If we use the same metric as in $\R^2,$ then it is clearly not locally isometric, right?

Comment: With suitable definitions of local and the metrics, the torus **is** locally isometric to the real plane. Therefore you absolutely should specify the metric! May be you are expected to embed the torus into $\Bbb{R}^3$ as a doughnut shape, and use the metric it gets from $\Bbb{R}^3$?

Answer (score 2):

Using the "Theorema Egregium", you know that gaussian curvature for surfaces embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is invariant by local isometry. In the Torus it is not constant, but in the plane it is (if we are talking about the embedded donut with its induced metric from $\mathbb{R}^3$).

Answer (score 1):

You can induce on the torus a metric which makes it, if I correctly guess what you mean, locally isometric to the plane - the torus with this geometry is sometimes called the flat torus. The most convenient representation of the torus here is to put $\mathbb T^2 := \mathbb R^2 / \mathbb Z^2$. Then you simply define the distance of two points $x,y \in \mathbb T^2$ by $d(x,y) := \inf \{ d(X,Y) \, | \, X \in [x], Y \in [y] \}$, where $d(X,Y)$ is the Euclidean distance of the points in the plane; also, you can take $\min$ instead of $\inf$ if you prefer.